# "...cannot be resolved to a variable." Why not?

Tags: java

```
public int getEntityIndex(String name){ 
    for(int i = 0; i < entities.length; i++){
        if(entities[i].getName().toUpperCase().equals(name.toUpperCase())){
            break;
        }
    }

    return i;
}
```

This code produces the error: `i` cannot be resolved to a variable. I'm guessing that variables declared inside the for loop declaration are outside the scope of the remainder of the method, but I was unable to find any information regarding this problem specifically.

After analyzing the code for a while, I am starting to see that using it is a bad idea (what if `entities[i]` never equals `name`? The method will return `entities.length - 1`, even if a match is not found. I think I'll use a `while(!found)` approach instead.

To clarify, I'm not asking how to fix the issue. I'm asking why this error is occurring.

Thanks!

Comment: "I'm guessing that variables declared inside the for loop declaration are outside the scope of the remainder of the method" - Exactly. The scope of `i` is only inside the `for` loop.

Comment: This is definitely a duplicate, but the variable is out of scope. "i" only exists inside the for loop. When you leave the for loop, i no longer exists.

This would work:
`int i = 0; for(; i < entities.length; i++){}return i;`

Comment: And why also this question has gotten zillion identical one sentence answers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot see `i` outside the `for` loop.

Try this:

```
public int getEntityIndex(String name) { 
    for(int i = 0; i < entities.length; i++){
        if(entities[i].getName().toUpperCase().equals(name.toUpperCase())){
            return i;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

PS: you could also use

```
entities[i].getName().equalsIgnoreCase(name)
```

instead of

```
entities[i].getName().toUpperCase().equals(name.toUpperCase())
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I'll definitely be changing `toUpperCase()` to `equalsIgnoreCase()`. Much simpler! I will mark this answer as correct since it concisely answers the question and provides other useful information. Thanks again.

Comment: @user1100793 Using this approach you also return the correct value interrupting the for loop. If the for loop ends without a match you don't return the array length any longer but a fixed value of your choice (like -1). You can also replace the final return with an exception throw.

Answer (score 0):

The scope of `i` is the for loop: `i`  only *exists* in the for loop.

Therefore, `i` cannot be used outside of it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

`i` is only in scope within the `for` loop. You can't use it outside unless you explicitly extend the scope by either defining `i` outside of the loop, or assigning it to another variable outside the loop.

Remember, a variable's scope is only **within** the block that it was defined. You're attempting to return `i`, but `i` doesn't exist outside the loop.

Comment: Thanks for answering!!

Answer (score 0):

In the last line, you return `i`.  The variable `i`, however, was created inside the scope of a for loop and doesn't exist outside of the for loop where you are trying to return it.

You can return `i` within the for loop, instead of "break."  You would need to return something else at the end.

You could also initialize `i` outside of the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

`i` is declared inside `for` loop, it's scope is only inside the loop. You cannot return it because its outside of scope.

Comment: Thank you for answering!

Answer (score 0):

The loop and everything is fine, but

```
return i;
```

.. i as a variable disappears once it leaves the loop, so the compiler doesn't actually know what to return. Here comes your error message

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can use another variable to return de value.

```
public int getEntityIndex(String name){ 
int j = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < entities.length; i++){
        if(entities[i].getName().toUpperCase().equals(name.toUpperCase())){
            break;
        }
    j++;
    }

return j;}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public int getEntityIndex(String name){ 
    for(int i = 0; i < entities.length; i++){
        if(entities[i].getName().toUpperCase().equals(name.toUpperCase())){
            return i; // If found return [i]
        }
    }
    return -1; //[i] was not found and return = -1;
}
```